# How to completely fit an AR Image ViewRenderable on targeted image?

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I am currently trying to place a 2D augmented image on a detected image using viewRenderable. I can render an image in AR. But it always placed with the wrong orientation. What I actually want to achieve is that an image is overlayed over the current poster, picture, banner.

This is my code.

test.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/tree" />
```

Below createModel() is called when plane or image gets detected.

MainActivity.java

```
 private void createModel(Anchor anchor, AugmentedImage image) {

    ViewRenderable
            .builder()
            .setView(this,R.layout.test)
            .build()
            .thenAccept(viewRenderable -> {

                setupModel(viewRenderable, anchor);


            });

}

private void setupModel(ViewRenderable viewRenderable, Anchor anchor    ) {
    AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
    anchorNode.setRenderable(viewRenderable);
    arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(anchorNode);
}
```

The problem with this is, the image always seems to be coming out of the plane or banner.
Can anyone help me to place the augmented image horizontally or change position, so that the augmented image hides the detected image?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Sceneform. Here is something I had worked on a long time back. Try to get something out of this if possible.
In order to orient the AR object while placing it, I had to play around with pose, localRotation, plane type and so on.
I will attach some snippets below.

```
if (trackable is Plane && trackable.isPoseInPolygon(hit.hitPose)) {
    val pose: Pose
    if (trackable.type == Plane.Type.VERTICAL) {
        isVertical = true
        pose = hit.hitPose
    } else {
        isVertical = false
        pose = hit.hitPose.extractTranslation()
        Log.d(tag, "Detected plane is horizontal")
    }

    // Other calculations...
     
    val camLook = arFragment.arSceneView.scene.camera.localRotation
    placeObject(fragment, pose, modelRenderable, distance, camLook)
}
```

I created a modelRenderable and passed all the parameters to placeObject function.
In the placeObject function, I then created a TransformableNode and assigned the renderable.

```
private fun placeObject(fragment: ArFragment, pose: Pose?, it: ModelRenderable, distance: Float, camLook: Quaternion) {
    val anchor = arSession!!.createAnchor(pose)
    val anchorNode = AnchorNode(anchor)
    anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.arSceneView.scene)

    val transformableNode = TransformableNode(fragment.transformationSystem)
    transformableNode.renderable = it
    transformableNode.setParent(anchorNode)
    //...
    if (isVertical) {
        val anchorUp = anchorNode.up
        transformableNode.setLookDirection(Vector3.up(), anchorUp)
    } else {
        camLook.x = 0f
        camLook.z = 0f
        transformableNode.localRotation = camLook
    }
    //...
}
```